# Unable to Push image to docker container registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

I have configured docker container registry and frontend as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gEs_zefNYA&t=1s&ab_channel=SelfTuts)

Container registry `(port 9001)` and frontend `(port 8080)` are working without any error, but when I try to push the image after tagging it I am getting error (mentioned below)

```
$ sudo docker tag nginx:1.17.0 localhost:9001/nginx:reg

$ sudo docker push localhost:9001/nginx:reg

The push refers to repository [localhost:9001/nginx]
Get http://localhost:9001/v2/: read tcp 127.0.0.1:39514->127.0.0.1:9001: read: connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue I was running the container registry on Ports `9001:9001` (host port: registry port) which was wrong, container registry expose services at port `5000`. So I re-ran container registry on Ports `5000:5000` and the issue was resolved